# Rounding background image of button

Tags: html, css

I'm required to have a rounded "growing" effect upon hovering over a button.[image]

Please see this link for a reference of how I need the button to work.
http://demo1.wpopal.com/corpec/home-4/

Currently I have achieved the "Not this" effect upon hover; though my employer wants the effect to have that bit of rounding.

I used the following css on the "not this" button to achieve the growing effect, though i need the edges to be rounded.

```css
.Custom-Button a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border: 1px solid #fdc900 !important;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fdc900, #fdc900);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size .5s, color .5s;
}

.Custom-Button a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Custom-Button">
  <a href="#">BUTTON</a>
</div>
```

I'm only allowed to use CSS to achieve the following effect and have already spent a day trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applying pseudo element for button solve it ! hope this help!

```css
.Custom-Button{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border: 1px solid #fdc900 !important;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:relative;
}
.Custom-Button a{
z-index:99;
text-decoration:none;
transition:color 1s;
}
.Custom-Button:hover:after{
  width:100%;
}
.Custom-Button:hover a{
  color:black;
}
.Custom-Button:after{
  width:0%;
  transition: width 1s;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
   border-radius:50px;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fdc900, #fdc900);
}
```

```html
<div class="Custom-Button">
  <a href="#">BUTTON</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Im having the same thing without pseudo elements - check out my answer. Will still upvote tho because its also good.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect, by combining z-index, and transitions of position and width of an underlying element:

When hovering, the child of the `filler`, will transition from

```
position: absolute; left: 50%;
```

to

```
position: absolute; left: 0;
```

while also resizing from `width: 0;` to `width: 100%;`

This is what will give you the desired effekt of "growing from the middle"

also you need to apply a border radius to your growing element

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 70px;
  border: 1px solid #fdc900 !important;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.filler {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 32px;
  /* half of <a> height */
  background-color: #fdc900;
  transition: width .5s, color .5s, left .5s;
}

a:hover .filler {
  z-index: 500;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
}

a:hover .text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="text">
    BUTTON
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>


</a>
```